# Right inverse of evaluation map from polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Say $E_1 : \mathbb{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) \mapsto f(1)$.

Is it sufficient to say there exists right inverse $S_R  : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{P}_3 $ from the following?

We see $\mathbb{P}_3$ has basis $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

So we can say $f(x) = a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ where $f(1)=a+b\cdot1+c\cdot1^2+d\cdot1^3$.

But it is clear $a+b\cdot1+c\cdot1^2+d\cdot1^3 = a+b+c+d$.

This gives $E_1 : a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 \mapsto a+b+c+d$

We then need to find some $g(x)$ where $S_R : a+b+c+d \mapsto g(x)\in\mathbb{P}_3$ such that $g(1)=a+b+c+d$.

**I assume this $g(x)$ need not be the $f(x)$ above. (Can I assume this?)**

Under this assumption, say $k=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$. Then $g(x)=k+kx+kx^2+kx^3$ gives $g(1)=k+k+k+k=4(k)=4(\frac{a+b+c+d}{4})=a+b+c+d$. And, so $g(1)=a+b+c+d$ as desired.

We can see $E_1\circ S_R : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

This is given by $f(1)=g(1)=x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ for $E_1\circ S_R : x_0 \mapsto g(x) \mapsto x_0$ where $f(x)$ is arbitrary vector over basis $B$ and $g(x)$ is defined with coefficients above.

Note: We can write $E_1$ as a row vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $S_R$ as a column vector $\frac 14 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}^T$ and arbitrary coordinate vector for $p(x) \in \mathbb{P}_3$ with $B = \{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3 = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d\end{pmatrix}^T$. The above can follow by multiplying these matrices.

I am reviewing an assigned question I got wrong to prep for my next exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try this?

$$S_R:k\rightarrow kx^3, \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}_3$$

Then:

$$E(S_R(k))=E(kx^3)=k*1^3=k$$

Therefore, $E(S_R(k))=k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{R}$, so that's a right inverse.

Comment: Thank you! My friend pointed out the constant function $k$ would also be in $\mathbb{P}_3$.  So, as you put it, would $S_R:k\rightarrow k, \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}_3$ also suffice?

Comment: Yep , exactly! I think this question is a matter of "spotting" the correct right inverse!